# How can I use Audodesk Forge Viewer to view 3d translated model in Autodesk Doc

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am developing My own project to view model from file in Autodesk Docs, but I am really confuse, How should I start from? for now I use 2 legged Authentication and got and access denied.Can someone help me to summarize overview steps to finally my custom viewer can view it?

Overall steps to view forge model in forge viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to start with one of our [tutorials](https://tutorials.autodesk.io), for example:

- [Simple Viewer](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/) - this tutorial guides you through the development of an application that manages the files of its users (designs are stored in a custom OSS bucket owned by the application)
- [Hubs Browser](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/) - this tutorial might be better for your use case as it builds an application that can access designs of its users in other APS applications such as Autodesk Docs, Autodesk Construction Cloud, or BIM360